# How to stub a method on a model copy in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, rspec

Say I have the next code:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.bar
    all.each(&:bar)
  end

  def bar
    # do something that I want stub in test
  end
end
```

Now I want to create test (Rspec):

```
foo = Foo.create
expect(foo).to receive(:bar)
Foo.bar
```

This test does not pass because `Foo.bar` calls other instance of the same model `foo`.

I wrote some complex code in such situations before, like:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:bar)
```

but this is not good, because there are no confidence that `foo` receives message (there could be several instances). And also `expect_any_instance_of` is not recommended by Rspec maintainers.

How do you test such code, is any best practice?

Answer (score 5):

If you want fine grained control over each instance, you can do something like this:

```
foo_1 = Foo.create
expect(foo_1).to receive(:bar).and_return(1)
foo_2 = Foo.create
expect(foo_2).to receive(:bar).and_return(2)

# This makes it so our specific instances of foo_1 and foo_2 are returned.
allow(Foo).to receive(:all).and_return([foo_1, foo_2])

expect(Foo.bar).to eq [1, 2]
```

Comment: It's ok for that synthetic example, but not for existed code. Reality is more complex..

Comment: I've done this a thousand times over, even when `Foo.bar` or `Foo#bar` is a complex method. If your code makes this answer unusable, please add more code and concerns to your original question, because as it stands this rspec test will work given your Foo example.

Comment: Say, it's not simple `all` scope, but complex chain of scopes. You could of course stub method chain, but it's not good for testing, as you should test method as a black box, as you do not know its implementation (even in my little example, how do you know it has `all` scope).

Comment: If you want to do completely black box testing, then you shouldn't put any expectations on any objects that check if they received certain methods. You would want to create your data, give your methods input, then check the output. That is different to your question though. Your question here was about your expectation being on a different instance than what was returned by `.all` and you state you want confidence that `Foo#bar` was called.

Comment: I'm not agree, method could be not only like pure function, so its output is not only what it returns, but also what it makes with data. In this case I want to ensure `foo` receives `bar` message. I changed `map` to `each` in my question to be more clear.

Comment: Using `each` or `map` doesn't change the fact that the test code I provided for you will work. If you want to provide actual code and show your concerns, then please update your question. As it stands, this answers your question, and without seeing the code there's no way to answer you further.

Answer (score -1):

In your example:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.bar
    all.map(&:bar)
  end

  def bar
    # do something that I want stub in test
  end
end
```

If `foo = Foo.new`

Note that `foo.bar` is different from `Foo.bar`.

The former is calling the instance method `def bar` ( which you want stubed ), while the later is calling the class method `def self.bar`.

In your test however,

```
foo = Foo.create
expect(foo).to receive(:bar)
Foo.bar
```

You are attempting to stub the instance method `def bar` ( expect(foo).to receive(:bar) ), while you are calling the class method `def self.bar` ( Foo.bar )

That is why it seems not to work.

Comment: I call `bar` on each instance in class method.